# Reducing space between lines with CSS (How come I can't emulate this style??)

Tags: html, css

Tearing my hair out trying to copy the link style Facebook uses. Using firebug I grabbed the computed css of the link in facebook, and applied it to my own. It renders the same except that, no matter what I try, I can't shrink the spaces between the lines like facebook does. No matter how small I set line-height, the line spacing remains the same. How can I shrink my line-heights like Facebook does, and how come I couldn't get there using the computed styles?

[image]

**Computed style for Facebook post links:**

```
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: transparent;
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
color: #3B5998;
cursor: pointer;
direction: ltr;
display: inline;
font-family: 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
height: auto;
line-height: 14px;
list-style-type: none;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
text-align: left;
text-decoration: none;
unicode-bidi: normal;
width: auto;
```

Here's a fiddle with the Facebook link computed css applied:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ptcd3/10/

---

**EDIT:**

Based on o.v.s example I noticed something even stranger- a line-height applied to the parent overrides the line-height applied on the element itself! This runs counter to cascading rules AND to what is being shown in the computed styles panel.

**See here:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ptcd3/23/
I apply a 9px line-height on the element, and a 6px line-height on the parent. The 9px line-height shows up in the computed styles, as it should, but the rendered result is the 6px line-height.

This disconnect between applied styles and computed styles can be seen both in Firebug and Chrome's css inspector. ???!

Answer (score 6):

Apply `display: block` and it will work fine.

Comment: SLaks- Thanks it does, BUT then how is the computed style for Facebook's link showing up as display:inline;?

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that computed rules reflect not only styles applied, but also inherited properties. Facebook likely has a semantic stylesheet with some setting on the parent element. If you look in the "applied styles" in firebug or similar, you would see how rules cascade and complement each other.

For instance, here http://jsfiddle.net/Ptcd3/16/ I'm applying line-height to the container and it gets inherited by the link! Increase it by a couple pixels and - *bam* - all done!

### Edit

You may want to look into http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/inline-format.html and http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced for better understanding of the math behind line-height calculations. If your ultimate goal is to "just get this working" you may want to stick with the other answer; but do play around with having multiple links in the container.